# Is $n=2$ the only root of $M(n!)$...?

Tags: number-theory, roots

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e1mgco1os22) can help till $n=9$, but are there other value larger than $2$ for which 
$$
M(n!)=0,
$$
where $M(n)$ is [Merten's function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensFunction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M(n!)=0$ then $n=2$ or $n\ge18$, see [A087989](https://oeis.org/A087989). Probably a few more terms could be computed using the Deléglise-Rivat algorithm, but the chance of finding other terms is remote.

---

Let's treat $\mu(n)$ as a random function which is 0 if $n$ is divisible by a square and $\pm1$ with probability 1/2 each otherwise. Then $M(x)$ is essentially $\sim y=:\frac{6}{\pi^2}x$ Bernoulli trials and so the 'probability' that $M(n)=0$ is $2^{-y}{y\choose y/2}\sim2^{-y}\cdot\frac{2^y}{\sqrt{\pi y/2}}=1/\sqrt{\pi y/2}=1/\sqrt{3x/\pi}$. So the 'chance' that $M(n!)=0$ is sharply decreasing with $n$, and in fact
$$
\int_{17.5}^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{3\Gamma(x+1)/\pi}}<2\cdot10^{-8}
$$
so the chance that another even *exists* is small. (Note the 17.5 comes from continuity correction; actually this choice is optimistic, with a more realistic value leading to a yet smaller 'probability'.)

Comment: Charles, thank you very much. For the interested reader: [Computing the Summation of the Möbius Function](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1047565447)